# Allow scrolling until last element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with some element inside it and I would like to allow the scrolling of the div until the last element.

This is what happens when I scroll:
[image]

And this is how I would like to make it:
[image]

Is it possible to do it?

Comment: You can try adding some bottom padding in the container

Comment: @AnkurAnand I know, but I was wondering if there is a more elegant and precise way to do it

Comment: I am not sure if that is possible with just CSS. I guess you would want to do it with just CSS right ?

Comment: @AnkurAnand Javascript should be fine as well, as I don't think it's possible only using CSS :-/

Comment: well I guess you can find out the height of the last div, then subtract it from the window's height. 
That should give you the amount of padding to leave at the bottom, and add that padding through CSS.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, it is quite simple without **any** javascript:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <section>hello</section>
    <section>hello</section>
    <section>hello</section>
    <section>hello</section>
    <section>hello</section>
    <section>hello</section>
    <section>hello</section>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
section { height: 100px; }

section:last-child { height: 100%; }

div {
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tan603rg/1/). The concept is just to use the parent div height as a height for the last item.

Comment: Amazing solution. Very elegant. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

Try achieve this using JS. Set a bottom margin to a last category equal to wrapper height minus last category height.

```
var wrapperHeight = $("#wrapper").innerHeight();
var lastCategory = $(".category:last-child");
var lastCategoryHeight = lastCategory.height();
var bottomMargin = wrapperHeight - lastCategoryHeight;
lastCategory.css({margin: "0 0 "+bottomMargin+"px 0"});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dmwjng3y/)

Comment: Very good solution, Thanks for that. But it seems that we can achieve the same without js

Answer (score 0):

Also it can be done with `scrollIntoView`, by scrolling into view the last element, this is the JS snippet:

```
items = document.querySelectorAll("section");i = items[items.length-1];i.scrollIntoView();
```

And this [is the jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/6gd3r0t6/2/)